# How can I multiply or divide value under the cursor by a repeat count?

Tags: vim

I know that it is possible to increment/decrement an integer by a repeat count using the `<repeat-count><ctrl>-a` and `<repeat-count><ctrl>-x` commands.

Now I was wondering whether there are analogous commands for multiplication and division. And if there is no such command, how can I implement this in my own .vimrc?

Comment: if you are asking built-in normal command, NO, there is not. But you can write function/mapping to do it. give an example, and show what do you want to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty attempt:

```
function! Multiply()
    " save count
    let cnt        = v:count1

    " save register v
    let old_reg    = getreg("v")

    " select the number under the cursor
    call search('\d\([^0-9\.]\|$\)', 'cW')
    normal v
    call search('\(^\|[^0-9\.]\d\)', 'becW')

    " yank it into register v then reselect
    normal "vygv

    " change the selection with the yanked number multiplied by the count
    execute "normal c" . @v * cnt

    " restore register v
    call setreg("v", old_reg)
endfunction

nnoremap <F5> :<C-u>call Multiply()<CR>
```

Now, press `5<F5>` to multiply the number under the cursor by `5`.

If you want to do it without mappings/functions:

```
v{motion}c<C-r>=<C-r>"*5<CR><Esc>
```

Comment: Try to learn what it means and you won't have to memorise it.

Comment: It would be great if we could use `.` to repeat the `<C-r>=<C-r>"` trick for a new value. `<C-r>=expand(@")*2<CR>` does also not work.